# Distribution of Data in GAN

Tags: generative-models, gan

Will Generator and Discriminator learns the Distribution of Data when it was trained?

If So Both Generator and Discriminator learns same distribution or different distributions ?

What can we interpret about the distribution of data for trained GAN ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two papers by [Arora, Risteski, and Zhang (2018)](https://openreview.net/forum?id=BJehNfW0-) and Arora, and [Zhang (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08224) showing that despite great hopes for achieving that, GANs seem to be pretty susceptible to mode collapse. Quoting abstract of the second paper:

> [...] A recent theoretical analysis in Arora et al (to appear at ICML
> 2017) [...] showed that the training objective can approach its
> optimum value even if the generated distribution has very low support
> ---in other words, the training objective is unable to prevent mode collapse. The current note reports experiments suggesting that such
> problems are not merely theoretical. It presents empirical evidence
> that well-known GANs approaches do learn distributions of fairly low
> support, and thus presumably are not learning the target distribution. [...]

As about your second question, the answer is also "no". Nothing in GANs forces generator and discriminator to learn the same thing, they only need to do their task correctly (generate or discriminate). Of course, as a side effect they both learn *something* about target distribution, but this doesn't have to be same thing.

Comment: I’ve seen a lot of mentions that GANs “memorize them data.” I just want to clarify that the generator itself never actually sees the training set data (it’s input is random noise). Instead the memorization is a collapse of the output to a few images.

Comment: @AlexR. fair point, this is not exactly memoization.

Comment: @Tim Its what i was actually expecting Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @Tim  Is it possible to learn different distribution for generator and discriminator for same target distribution?

Comment: @SSVarshini not sure what you mean by discriminator “learning distribution“ in here. It is a classifier, that learns to classify examples that it’s given.

Comment: I mean to classify samples discriminator should learn the distribution of real samples is my point correct ?

Comment: @SSVarshini it depends what you mean by learning the distribution. For example, imagine that you are given task to classify by hand documents if that are written in Italian or French. I can do this without problem despite not knowing any of those languages. Sure the task needs knowing *something* about the languages, but doesn’t need knowing them.

Comment: The generator will learn about the data(distribution), Is this correct  ?